# Flutter WebView not working M1 chipset macOS 11.4

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on an M1 mac.

For several days now, I am struggling with a problem implementing a widget **' WebView'** in my project.
I can't wrap my hand around this problem, I have tried all of the possibilities I have found on the internet.

1. I have added the `webview_flutter: ^2.0.10` dependency to the **pubspec.yaml** file
2. Code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  const Main({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'WebView',
        home: WebView(
            initialUrl: ('https://google.com'),
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted));
  }
}
```

3. I have followed instructions from other posts and YouTube videos and I have duplicated an iTerm app, right-clicked on it --> get info -->
   translate by Rosseta --> cd to project app --> `sudo gem install cocoapods` (I think it's necessary for WebView to work) --> `sudo gem install ffi`
4. I have played with android --> app --> build.gradle -->
   minSdkVersion 16/19

Unfortunately, none of these helped me get any closer to the solution for the problem, I can compile the code both on Android Emulator, and on iOS Simulator, however in both scenarios the application is just blank

[PHOTO Flutter doctor, code, etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6oQi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by running pod install with **arch -x86_64**

So here are the steps that worked for me:-
Uninstall pods to start fresh,

- sudo gem uninstall cocoapod
- sudo gem uninstall ffi

Now will reinstall again with arch -x86_64 value,

- arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods
- arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update

This should work.
By this we exclude arm64 architecture.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. However, I have avoided this issue by using  ```flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.4.0``` and ```MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/home_page',
      routes: {
        '/keycloak': (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
              url: "http://test.apps.okdtst.eskom.software/auth",
              appBar: new AppBar(
                title: new Text("Widget webview"),
              ),
            ),
        '/home_page': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/new_question': (context) => NewQuestion(),
      },
    );```